# Custom Wordpress code that returns ul

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to write custom Wordpress shortcode that returns ordered list by specified parameters given by the user.
Example:
[bulleted_listelements="James;Joan;
Teo;Jimm"] which return
 1. James
 2. Joan
 3. Teo
 4. Jimm

Can I do this or I must use [bulleted_listelements]James;Joan;
Teo;Jimm[/bulleted_listelements]
But if the user just enter James and Teo, ex.?

Comment: You should read this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

```
[bulleted_listelements]James;Joan; Teo;Jimm[/bulleted_listelements]
[bulleted_listelements]James[/bulleted_listelements]
```

Add code in your function.php. [More info](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/)

```
function bulleted_listelements_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    $data = explode(';', $content);
    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)):
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
                <li><?php echo $d; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>

        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    else:
        $content = do_shortcode($content);
    endif;
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('bulleted_listelements', 'bulleted_listelements_shortcode');
```

[image]

Comment: You are great, Ravi Patel! Thank you!